# Prove that a polynomial ring is integrally closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $V \subseteq {\mathbb{A}}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the curve defined by $x^2-y^2+x^3=0$, and let $\mathbb{C}\left [ V \right ]$ the coordinate ring of $V$. Let $\Theta :=\bar{y}/\bar{x} \in \mathbb{C}\left ( V \right )$. I must show that the ring $B:=\mathbb{C}\left [ V \right ]\left [ \Theta  \right ]$ is a UFD.

I could show that this ring is a FD, because it is noetherian, but I am not sure how to prove that the factorizations are unique. Any help would be appreciated. I also tried to show that $B$ is isomorphic to a UFD, but i am not sure what domain would be suitable for this argument.

(Note: I need to prove that $B$ is a UFD to say that $B$ is integrally closed.)

Comment: $B$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb C[V]$, so it is integrally closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us show that the $\Bbb{C}[V][\Theta]$ is in fact generated by $\Theta$ as a $\Bbb{C}$-subalgebra of $\Bbb{C}(V).$

Define a morphism $\phi$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\phi : \Bbb{C}[x,y]&\to\Bbb{C}[t]\\
x&\mapsto t^2 - 1,\\
y&\mapsto t^3 - t.
\end{align*}
It is not difficult to check that this factors through the quotient map $\Bbb{C}[x,y]\to\Bbb{C}[V].$

Now, clearly $\phi$ is a surjection onto $\Bbb{C}[t^2 - 1,t^3 - t],$ so that $\Bbb{C}[x,y]/\ker\phi\cong\Bbb{C}[t^2 - 1,t^3 - t].$ We need to prove that $\ker\phi = (x^3 + x^2 - y^2)$. To do so, note that both $\ker\phi$ and $(x^3 + x^2 - y^2)$ are prime. Since $\ker\phi$ is not maximal ($\Bbb{C}[x,y]/\ker\phi$ is visibly not a field), it is properly contained in some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}.$ This gives us a chain of prime ideals
$$
(0)\subsetneq (x^3 + x^2 - y^2)\subseteq \ker\phi\subsetneq\mathfrak{m}.
$$
But, $\dim\Bbb{C}[x,y] = 2,$ so that we must have $(x^3 + x^2 - y^2) =  \ker\phi.$

Thus, we get an isomorphism
$$
\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3 + x^2 - y^2)\cong\Bbb{C}[t^2 - 1,t^3 - t],
$$
and $y/x = \Theta$ in the fraction field of the left hand side corresponds to $t$ in the fraction field of the right hand side, because $x = \Theta^2 - 1$ and $y = \Theta^3 - \Theta.$ Now, it is easy to see the result, as $\Bbb{C}[V][\Theta]\cong\Bbb{C}[t^2 - 1,t^3 - t][t] = \Bbb{C}[t].$ This implies that $\Bbb{C}[V][\Theta] = \Bbb{C}[\Theta]$ (and that $\Theta$ satisfies no relations over $\Bbb{C}$) as claimed initially.

---

**Edit:** As user26857 notes, the initial solution I presented (below) is not totally rigorous -- we need some condition on $x$ and $y$ to guarantee that $R[\frac{y}{x}]\cong R[T]/(xT - y).$ In fact, it isn't true that $\Bbb{C}[V][T]/(xT-y)\cong\Bbb{C}[V][y/x]$: the ideal $(xT-y)$ should be $(xT -y, T^2 - x - 1)$ -- this second relation is implicitly assumed and explicitly used. What is below can be made rigorous, either by justifying that the kernel of $\Bbb{C}[V][T]\to\Bbb{C}[V][y/x]$ is precisely $(xT -y, T^2 - x - 1),$ or by writing $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\Theta$ and justifying that $\Theta$ satisfies no additional relations.

First, note that $\Bbb{C}[V]\cong\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3 + x^2 - y^2)$ and observe that $\Theta^2 = \frac{y^2}{x^2} = \frac{x^3 + x^2}{x^2} = x + 1.$

Now, using the fact that $x = \Theta^2-1,$ we find
\begin{align*}
\Bbb{C}[V][\Theta]&\cong(\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3 + x^2 - y^2))[\Theta]/(x\Theta - y)\\
&= \Bbb{C}[x,y,\Theta]/(x\Theta - y,x^3 + x^2 - y^2)\\
&= \Bbb{C}[y,\Theta]/((\Theta^2 - 1)\Theta - y,(\Theta^2 - 1)^3 + (\Theta^2 - 1)^2 - y^2)
\end{align*}
However, it is now clear that $y = \Theta^3 - \Theta,$ and hence that
\begin{align*}
(\Theta^2 - 1)^3 + (\Theta^2 - 1)^2 - y^2 &=(\Theta^2 - 1)^3 + (\Theta^2 - 1)^2 - (\Theta^3 - \Theta)^2\\
&= (\Theta^2 - 1)^2(\Theta^2 - 1 + 1) - (\Theta^3 - \Theta)^2\\
&= \Theta^2(\Theta^2 - 1)^2 - (\Theta^3 - \Theta)^2\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

As such, we find that $$((\Theta^2 - 1)\Theta - y,(\Theta^2 - 1)^3 + (\Theta^2 - 1)^2 - y^2) = ((\Theta^2 - 1)\Theta - y),$$ so that
\begin{align*}
\Bbb{C}[V][\Theta]&\cong \Bbb{C}[y,\Theta]/((\Theta^2 - 1)\Theta - y,(\Theta^2 - 1)^3 + (\Theta^2 - 1)^2 - y^2)\\
&=\Bbb{C}[y,\Theta]/((\Theta^2 - 1)\Theta - y)\\
&=\Bbb{C}[\Theta^3 - \Theta,\Theta]\\
&= \Bbb{C}[\Theta].
\end{align*}
A polynomial ring in one variable over a field is clearly a UFD.

Comment: An isomorphism of the form $R[T]/(xT-y)\simeq R[\frac yx]$ can fail if we do not know that $R$ is integrally closed, and this is exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: @user26857 Good point; in fact, assuming $R$ is integrally closed is not even enough. Take for example $R = \Bbb{Z}$ and $x = y = 2,$ then $\Bbb{Z}[2/2] = \Bbb{Z},$ but $\Bbb{Z}[T]/(2T - 2)$ has zero divisors. Of course in this case, the result holds, but I've added another argument which does not rely on this, as I'm not sure off the top of my head what the correct condition on $x$ and $y$ is to guarantee the isomorphism holds. (It should be some sort of relative primeness.)

Comment: When I asked if $R[T]/(xT-y)$ is isomorphic to $R[\frac yx]$ I have thought on when the natural morphism $\varphi:R[T]\to R[\frac yx]$, $\varphi(T)=\frac yx$ has $\ker\varphi=(xT-y)$. In the trivial case $x=y$ this holds iff $x$ is invertible.

Comment: I forgot to say that there is no chance to get $\ker\varphi=(xT-y)$ if $R$ is not integrally closed (unless $x$ is invertible).

Comment: @user26857 Well, unless I'm misunderstanding something, the isomorphism holds precisely when $\ker\varphi =(xT-y),$ because $R[T]\to R[\frac yx]$ is always surjective. The largest $R[\frac yx]$ can be is when it is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable, in which case $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: The kernel of the map $\mathbb C[V][T]\to\mathbb C[V][\frac yx]$, $T\mapsto\frac yx$ is not $(xT-y)$. It contains $T^2-x+1$ which does not belong to the ideal $(xT-y)$.

Comment: @user26857 ah of course: I also implicitly quotiented by that relation when I wrote $\Theta^2 = x+1$. Thank you, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

We have $B=\mathbb C[\bar x,\bar y,\frac{\bar y}{\bar x}]=\mathbb C[\bar x,\frac{\bar y}{\bar x}]=\mathbb C[\frac{\bar y}{\bar x}]$, since $\bar x=(\frac{\bar y}{\bar x})^2-1$.

Now the only thing to prove is that $\frac{\bar y}{\bar x}$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbb C$. If $f\in\mathbb C[t]$, $f=a_0+a_1t+\dots+a_nt^n$ is such that $f(\frac{\bar y}{\bar x})=0$, then $\sum_{i=0}^na_i\bar x^{n-i}\bar y^i=0$. Removing the residue classes we get $\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^{n-i}y^i\in(y^2-x^2-x^3)$. It is easily seen that this holds if and only if $a_i=0$ for all $i$.